# Creating an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I need a method `coins` that takes an integer and maps it to an array of its integer-divisions by the numbers from 2 to 4. I need to keep doing this until all numbers reach zero, and then count the elements in the array. Example is as follows:

```
coins(5) # => 11
```

This is derived as follows:

```
# 5
# => [2, 1, 1]
# => [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]] 
# => [[[0, 0, 0], 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Below is what needs to happen to each index of the array if the number rounded down does not equal 0.

```
def coins(n)
  arr = (n/2), (n/3), (n/4)
  i = 0
  while i < arr.length
    if arr[i] != 0
      arr[i] = (n/2), (n/3), (n/4)
    end
    i += 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe it's me but I don't understand what you coins method should do can you put the pseudo-code of this one maybe it will be clearer for me.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa Basically how to create the subarrays until all the elements are 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def coins n
  a = [n]
  a.replace(a.flat_map{|e| e.zero? ? e : [e/2, e/3, e/4]}) until a.all?(&:zero?)
  a.length
end

coins(5) # => 11
```